# Solaris multi-threaded stack and heap monitoring on out-of-memory

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, out-of-memory, solaris-10

I am running a multi-threaded C program on Solaris 10. I am getting some memory issue there with out-of-memory shown or a crash. How can I monitor heap and stack size dynamically to assess in a proactive (before out-of-memory situation) as well as reactive (after out-of-memory situation) mode?

Comment: If you're running 64-bit processes, monitoring application memory isn't going to help you in an out-of-memory situation.  The application needs to properly handle dynamic memory allocation failures from calls such as `mmap()` or `malloc()` - Solaris isn't Linux and it won't lie to you about memory being available when it's not.  A 64-bit Solaris application won't be able to tell it's about to run out of memory until the server itself actually is out of free memory and the operating system returns failure with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` for attempts to get more memory.